# python-whois extend TLD for domain

Tags: python

i have a problem with pipe python-whois https://pypi.org/project/python-whois/.
I am trying to extend the functionality of the library with additional TLD domains that I need. However, adding according to the instructions included in the documentation doesn't do anything, also removing the cache files. Maybe someone of you tried to do this? This library is the most consistent, so I would like to stay with it.
Greetings
[screen addidtional TLD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCDYN.png)

Comment: Which TLD do you want to add?

Comment: Also, can you share what have you tried?

Comment: I want to add .live for example

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to extend with the .live TLD and am trying as posted in the documentation.  So, I add the Whoislive class

```
class WhoisLive(WhoisEntry):
""""Whois parser for .live domains
"""
regex = {
    'domain_name':      'Domain Name: *(.+)',
    'registrar':        'registrar: *(.+)',
    'whois_server':     'Whois Server: *(.+)',
    ...
}

def __init__(self, domain, text):
    if text.strip() == 'NOT FOUND':
        raise PywhoisError(text)
    else:
        WhoisEntry.__init__(self, domain, text)
```

and in parse.py in the load method:

```
elif domain.endswith('.live'):
            return WhoisLive(domain, text)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).